# meteor build command faild with message "killedking"

Tags: meteor

```
meteor create cool
cd cool
meteor build /root/cool/production --directory --server=wdksw.com:3030
Killedking                                   \
```

There is no `production` directory appear. How to use this command?

Comment: It seems to be structured properly, but you shouldn't generally build into a location in your source tree. Any errors or notifications during the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knows its 6 1/2 years later, but just in case it helps anyone...

It was "Killed" by the OS, but appeared over another console message being displayed at the time which ended "......king". maybe something to do with linking.

And it will probably have been killed because the OS ran out of memory, try setting NODE_OPTIONS and/or TOOL_NODE_FLAGS environmental variables, eg on Linux

```
  export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=16384
  export TOOL_NODE_FLAGS=--max_old_space_size=16384

  meteor build ...
```